# Python: split and select the best one for undefined number of entries

Tags: python

Sorry if the question is silly...
I am looking for the trick in python that allow splitting the line and selecting the best value and the corresponding source, but the actual number of entries is unknown, it can be from 1 up to 100.

```
x = "32.1 (PDBbind), 50.1 (BDB), 83.0 (BMOAD_4832)"
for i in x.split(","):
    b = []
    if float(i.split()[0]) < float(b[0]):
        b = i.split()[0]
```

I get an error "List index out of range".

Comment: What makes a value the _best_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
b = []
if float(i.split()[0]) < float(b[0]):
                              #^ b is an empty list, b[0] will raise that error
```

If I understand your problem right, concise solution to this would be:

```
>>> max(x.split(","), key=lambda x: float(x.split()[0]))
' 83.0 (BMOAD_4832)'
```

Comment: thanks! lambda is the function that I missed from my python studies...time to fix that! Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `List index out of range` because `b = []` and then `float(b[0])`.